# When a AWS Auto Scaling Group is scaling out which ec2 instance is considered to be Primary

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, auto

When a AWS Auto Scaling Group is scaling out which ec2 instance is considered to be Primary?

Meaning if my ASG is scaling out which ec2 instance ASG considers as a base instance?

Because if I am making changes in the First ec2 instance I created those are not transfered to other new ec2 instance created by ASG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data is not automatically copied from existing instances to new instances. You can use lifecycle hooks to copy the data or an Amazon RDS database including replicas.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/lifecycle-hooks.html

Comment: what is metric dimensions AutoScalingGroup? If ASG scales out so of which ec2 instance its checking the cpu utilization/scale out policy

Comment: Amazon EC2 sends metrics to CloudWatch that describe your Auto Scaling instances. These metrics are available for any EC2 instance, not just those in an Auto Scaling group. 
You can filter the data based on the AutoScalingGroupName, ImageId, InstanceId.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/viewing_metrics_with_cloudwatch.html#ec2-cloudwatch-metrics